# Problem with With

Tags: core-language

I am puzzled by`With`. it does not seem to work. Please see example below (I have also used `Evaluate` and `N` on it, to no avail).

```
force[x_] := a x - b x^3

With[{a = 1, b = 1}, force[1]]
```

> ```
> a - b
> ```

Being naive, I would expect to see 0 as a result; `a` and `b` should have been transformed into 1 by `With`.

Comment: Use `Block` instead.

Comment: You might be interested in [Leonid Shifrin](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236808/499167) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6236458/499167) question

Answer (score 6):

`With` replaces occurrences of declared constants with their values, but it won't change the definition of `force[]` outside its scope.   To do that you'd need to include the function definition like so :-

```
With[{a = 1, b = 1},
 force[x_] := a x - b x^3;
 force[1]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Another option is to use `Block`, which does dynamic scoping

```
Block[{a = 1, b = 1}, force[1]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

More info [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ScopingConstructs.html).

Comment: Didn't feel the need to post a seperate A. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you - the first solution is too cumbersome, would mean repeating definitions. I was aware of Block and Module, but I read that With is much faster, so I was hoping to use that. I must say I still do not understand why With does not change a and b inside force for the purpose of this calculation: it wouldnt mean changing it inside the definition of force, just for this evaluation.

Comment: @Alberto - In your original form the definition of `force[]` can be found in `DownValues@force`.  `With` simply doesn't affect that definition, being defined outside its scope.

Comment: @Alberto, what you are describing is dynamic scoping, and `Block` is what does that. `With` is for a different purpose

Comment: @Alberto And the speed difference between the two is absolutely negligible for most applications.

Comment: I see - speed actually could be an issue as this is going to go inside a montecarlo. Thanks for your help (I still think the behaviour is counterintuitive - but alas this is often the price to pay for Mathematica's advantages)